# how to get JSON result of YQL ordered by the given XPATHs

Tags: json, xpath, yql

I am trying to crawl a website.
I have made my YQL query with XPATh for **headline, Date, then Body** of the article.

```
select * from html where url="mywebsite.com/myarticle" and xpath="headlineXpath | DateXpath | BodyXpath"
```

now the result in xml is headline, date, then body and this is what i am looking for.
but when i get the result in json format, i get it in another order **headline, body then date**
my question: how can i get the result in json according to the order of the given XPATHS?
thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show a sample of the XML and the JSON? and the desired JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
select headline, date, body from html where ...
```

instead of using *? I don't know much YQL so I may be off on the arguments, but the idea is to specify the order of fields using explicit selection instead of the wildcard.

Comment: Thanks Lars for your reply.
when i get the result in XML format i get the result as
<xml><headline>Headline</headline><date>date</date><bodytags>body</bodytags><xml> while in Json format i get it
result:{h6:headline}{p:body}{b:date}
now... what i am looking for is to get it as headline,date, then body in json format
thanks again

Comment: @Alaa, I changed my answer... does that help?

Comment: Thanks Lars, really appreciated,, but the problem is: i am building crawler and tags are not standard (for example headline might be h2 for a website while it might be 'strong' for another and so on)

Comment: @Alaa, do you have a way, then, to systematically know what order to put them in, regardless of what tags are used for each field? If not, it seems to me this is an information problem before it becomes a YQL issue.